# Average case complexity examples

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I found many examples for the worst case and best case complexity, but average-case complexity was the same as worst-case complexity in most cases. Are there examples where average-case complexity can be different from worst-case complexity? If there are, please some cases in both recursive and iterative cases.

Comment: In the first sentence "I found ... average-case is the same as best-case in most cases". In the second sentence "examples where average-case can be different from worst-case". Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I am using Grammarly extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithms based on partitioning using a pivot will typically have poor worst-case performance, because of the possibility of choosing an inefficient partition (i.e. most elements end up in the same side):

- [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) has time complexity O(n log n) in the average case, but O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case.
- [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) has time complexity O(n) in the average case, but O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case.

Note that both quicksort and quickselect can be implemented with or without recursion.

Algorithms based on [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) also typically have poor worst-case performance, because of the possibility of hash collision. For example, basic operations on a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) are O(1) time in the average case, but O(n) time in the worst case.

More generally, algorithms designed for efficient performance on roughly-uniform data are likely to have worse performance on very non-uniform data, for example [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) degrades from an average O(log log n) on uniform data to O(n) in the worst case.

Comment: Can you please give some examples of best-case complexity also?

Comment: Your question says you found many examples for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,

Average case complexity tends to be in between best and worst case in absolute terms.
but, the Complexities are dependent on input size and distribution
so they are expressed in the function of n which makes them either
equal to best case or worst case most of the times

So , No for the specific answer you are looking for.

Moreover Average case complexity has various constraints associated with it for e.g

```
* A probability distribution on the inputs has to be specified.
* Simple assumption: all equally likely inputs of size n.
* Sometimes this assumption may not hold for the real inputs.
* The analysis might be a difficult math challenge.
* Even if the average-case complexity is good, the worst-case
one may be very bad.
```

so , it's less likely to be used